# Diagrams next to question captions

Tags: feature-request, questions

This is in regards of the subtopic Go and an extended copy of a post asked on the now-defunct meta.Go.SE.

In the long run, there will be a lot of questions in the form of "Question about some move in some game". To make sure users have a basic understanding of the actual content of the question, I'd suggest to add little diagrams next to the questions.

To a Go player, those diagrams will usually immediately tell about the content, helping them to decide if they can answer. At least it would encourage them to have a look, since noone likes to click on the umpteenth "What are properties of and rationale behind this fuseki move?" or "What's the status of this group?".

This is linked to removing diagram code from question excerpts, which makes the excerpts unreadable and basically useless.

The previous statement from the official side was to put this up as a feature request, so here it is again. It was also said that it would be a major change, so this is more of a reference.